# Dreamweaver CS3 - auto closing custom tags - unable to stop

Tags: php, tags, dreamweaver

I have inherited some PHP code which creates custom tags thus:

```
<group_description<?php echo $result['products_id'];?> style="display:none">
     ++some text here++
  </group_description<?php echo $result['products_id'];?>>
```

So this generates something like:

```
<group_description11 style="display:none">
     ++some text here++
  </group_description11>
```

Problem is that Dreamweaver CS3 will (when opening the php document - it's not on save - only if you close then reopen) will rewrite the last line to:

```
</group_description><?php echo $result['products_id'];?>>
```

so the resulting HTML output  becomes:

```
</group_description>11>
```

I have all code rewriting OFF in DW and work only in code view - I can find nothing anywhere on this - has anybody any suggestions?

Baffled - Graeme

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are willing to lose all auto close functionality, but you could [turn off the feature](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7bd7a.html#WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7bd5a).  The following link says

> **Note**: *By default, Dreamweaver determines when a closing tag is needed and inserts if automatically. You can change this default behavior so that Dreamweaver inserts a closing tag after you type the final angle bracket (>) of the opening tag. Alternatively, the default behavior can be to insert no closing tag at all. Select Edit > Preferences > Code Hints, and then select one of the Close Tags options.*

Potentially changing the behavior to insert a closing tag after you type the final angle bracket would resolve this issue as well and you would not lose all auto close functionality

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi - Close tags is already off I'm afraid. I'm probably going to just replace the custom tags with <div> and use a class name instead